# Nested "for loop" searches in SQL - Azure CosmosDB

Tags: sql, node.js, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I am using Cosmos DB and have a document with the following simplified structure:

```
{
    "id1":"123",
    "stuff": [
        {
            "id2": "stuff",
            "a": {
                "b": {
                    "c": {
                        "d": [
                            {
                                "e": [
                                    {
                                        "id3": "things",
                                        "name": "animals",
                                        "classes": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "ostrich",
                                                "meta": 1
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "big ostrich",
                                                "meta": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id3": "default",
                                        "name": "other",
                                        "classes": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "green trees",
                                                "meta": 1
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "name": "trees",
                                                "score": 1
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My issue is - I have an array of these documents and need to search `name` to see if it matches my search word. For example I want both `big trees` and `trees` to return if a user types in `trees`.

So currently I push every document into an array and do the following:

`For each` document

`for each` `stuff`

`for each` `a.b.c.d[0].e`

`for each` `classes` 
`var splice = name.split(' ')`

`if (splice.includes(searchWord))`

return `id1`, `id2` and `id3`.

Using cosmosDB I am using SQL with the following code:

```
client.queryDocuments(
    collection,
    `SELECT * FROM root r`
).toArray((err, results) => {stuff});
```

This effectively brings every document in my collection into an array to perform the search manually above as mentioned.

This is going to cause issues when I have 1000s or 1,000,000s of documents in the array and I believe I should be leveraging the search mechanics available within Cosmos itself. Is anyone able to help me to work out what SQL query would be able to perform this type of function?

Having searched everything is it also possible to search the 5 latest documents?

Thanks for any insight in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Is anyone able to help me to work out what SQL query would be able to
> perform this type of function?

According to your sample and description, I suggest you using [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query#array-functions) in cosmos db sql. Please refer to my sample:

sample documents:

```
[
    {
        "id1": "123",
        "stuff": [
            {
                "id2": "stuff",
                "a": {
                    "b": {
                        "c": {
                            "d": [
                                {
                                    "e": [
                                        {
                                            "id3": "things",
                                            "name": "animals",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ostrich",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "big ostrich",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id3": "default",
                                            "name": "other",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "green trees",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "trees",
                                                    "score": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id1": "456",
        "stuff": [
            {
                "id2": "stuff2",
                "a": {
                    "b": {
                        "c": {
                            "d": [
                                {
                                    "e": [
                                        {
                                            "id3": "things2",
                                            "name": "animals",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ostrich",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "trees",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id3": "default2",
                                            "name": "other",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "green trees",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "trees",
                                                    "score": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id1": "789",
        "stuff": [
            {
                "id2": "stuff3",
                "a": {
                    "b": {
                        "c": {
                            "d": [
                                {
                                    "e": [
                                        {
                                            "id3": "things3",
                                            "name": "animals",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ostrich",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "big",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id3": "default3",
                                            "name": "other",
                                            "classes": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "big trees",
                                                    "meta": 1
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

query :

```
SELECT distinct c.id1,stuff.id2,e.id3 FROM c
join stuff in c.stuff
join d in stuff.a.b.c.d
join e in  d.e
where ARRAY_CONTAINS(e.classes,{name:"trees"},true)
or ARRAY_CONTAINS(e.classes,{name:"big trees"},true)
```

output:

[image]

> 2.Having searched everything is it also possible to search the 5 latest
> documents?

Per my research, features like `LIMIT` is not supported in cosmos so far. However , `TOP` is supported by cosmos db. So if you could add sort field(such as date or id), then you could use sql:

```
select top 5 from c order by c.sort desc
```

Comment: Hey, that Query worked really well except for one part - it doesn't include the same functionality as the `splice.includes(searchWord)` did in the original function - is there a way to include in the query somehow? The reason being - i need them to just search `trees` and find anything with the word `trees` in.

Comment: @JDT I found your newer question and post my idea there. please check it.Thanks.